# constructors java trying to make a simple program

Tags: java, constructor

The program is suppose to add employees to the array and then for each employee/manager is assigned an allocation. an allocation depending on if they are a manager/employee is different amount and at the end all allocations are added.

Where i am at is trying t figure out how to calculate the total after all employees are added.

```
package pay;

import java.util.*;



public class manager
 {
    static double allocation =0;
    public manager(String string, int i, String type) {
        // 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // construct a Manager object
       manager boss = new manager("Carl Cracker", 80000, "QA");
      int total = 0;

       Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];

       // fill the staff array with Manager and Employee objects

     //  staff[0] = boss;
       staff[1] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 0,"Dev");
       staff[2] = new Employee("Tommy Tester", 0,"QA");

       // print out information about all Employee objects
      int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
      {

       total += allocation;
      }
    }
 }



 class Employee
 {

public Employee(String string, int i, String string2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
public double Employee(String n, int s, String type)
   {
    if (type.equals("Dev")) 
           allocation = 1000;
       else if (type.equals("QA")) 
           allocation = 500;
       else
           allocation = 250;
    return allocation;
   }
    private double getallocation()
    {
    return allocation;
    }

    private double allocation;
    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }
    private String name;

 }

 class Manager extends Employee
 {

    public Manager(String string, int i, String string2) {
        super(string, i, string2);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /*
     n the employee's name
     s the salary

        */
    public double manager(String n, double s)
    {
    n= getName();
    double getAllocation = 0;
    s = getAllocation;
       s=s+300;
    return s;
   }
 }
```

Comment: And the problem is ? ...

Comment: Why do you have a `manager` class **and** a `Manager` class? Also, **why**?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Maybe to remember java distinguish upper case and lower case zz

Comment: Problem is trying to print result of allocation the lower manager i was trying to create a constructor .

Comment: Your question does not seem to match the title - the question is about summing all allocations but the title is about constructor.

Comment: i am summing the allocations and the program is using constuctors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 then the allocations can be summed using the following expression:

```
Arrays.stream(staff).mapToDouble(Employee::getAllocation).sum();
```

As an aside (or helpful hint) these types of class structures often use a composite design pattern. It would look like this:

```
interface Employee {
    double getAllocation();
    EmployeeType getType();
}

class IndividualContributor implements Employee {
    private Manager boss;
    public double getAllocation() {
        return getType().getAllocation();
    }
}

class Manager implements Employee {
    private final List<Employee> staff;
    public double getAllocation() {
        return getType().getAllocation() + 300;
    }
}
```

And your employee type, currently a `String` would generally be implemented as an `enum`:

```
enum EmployeeType {
    QA(500), 
    DEV(100),
    OTHER(250);

    private final double allocation;

    EmployeeType(double allocation) {
        this.allocation = allocation;
    }

    public double getAllocation() {
        return allocation;
    }
}
```